# How PHPMyAdmin get query statics?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Dear friends: I'm developing a php server monitor for a client. One of the monitor's sections is related to MySQL.

In PHPmyadmin the section Server Status > Status queries show an amount of queries. I thought that was extracted from the "SHOW STATUS" mysql command. But... Differs!

When i go in PHPmyadmin to the section Server Status > Server Status Variables, the system displays the same values that "Status Queries" section. 
But when i get the results of "SHOW STATUS" command, the values is not the same".

My English level is too poor to explain the case correctly. So, I will show an example: 
In Server Status > Status Queries i can see, in the table:

```
Sentences  |  #  | per hour| %
---------------------------------
select     | 365 |  51.4   |25.29
set option | 266 |  37.4   |18.43
```

When i go to Server Status > Server Status Variables, i can see:

```
Variable       | Value | Description
---------------------------------
Com select     |  365  | Blah Blah....
Com set Option |  266  | Blah Blah....
```

But if i run "SHOW STATUS", i obtain:

```
Variable       | Value 
-----------------------------
com_select     |   1  
com_set_Option |   2
```

And, in this point, my brain explode.... 
Can do you enlighten me?
PD: Again, Sorry if my English is too poor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

To get the [server status values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-status.html) as shown in PhpMyAdmin

> With a GLOBAL modifier, the statement displays the global status values. A global status variable may represent status for some aspect of the server itself (for example, Aborted_connects), or the aggregated status over all connections to MySQL (for example, Bytes_received and Bytes_sent). If a variable has no global value, the session value is displayed.
>
> With a SESSION modifier, the statement displays the status variable values for the current connection. If a variable has no session value, the global value is displayed. LOCAL is a synonym for SESSION.
>
> **If no modifier is present, the default is SESSION.**

Comment: Many Many Many thanks! The GLOBAL modifier is all was I looking for